# Adding a field to a collection in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a collection that stores session information. I'm using the following javascript command to add "name" field if it's not already exists. If it is, I just update all the records with the value I provided.

> session.update({},{$set:{"name":x}}, function(e,c){....});

However, this code is not working. It only do update when the second user sign in and it only do so on the first record. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Pass `{ multi: true }` as the third argument. By default, update operations only affect one document.

Comment: Also, you may want to specify what documents you want affected in the query object (first argument).